# Validating 2 rules before launching the success page

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a school homework assignment but I am stuck on the 6th question.

> Add a set of radio buttons to the form to accept a level of entry such as GCSE, AS or A2. Write a function that displays the level of entry to the user in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected

My code is meant to validate the Examination Number, Name, and Subject before launching another page called "success". In this question I am supposed to add a new rule where the user has to choose a level of study such as "GCSE" "AS" and "A2". Here is my code so far.

```
    <head>
<title>Exam entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
 var result = true;
 var msg="";
 var n=(document.ExamEntry.exam.value.length);


 if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="")
 {
  msg+="You must enter your name \n";
  document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
  document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
  result = false;
 }

 if (document.ExamEntry.exam.value=="")
 {  
  msg+="You must enter the EN \n";
  document.ExamEntry.exam.focus();
  document.getElementById('exam').style.color="red";
  result = false;
 }

 if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="")
 {  
  msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
  document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
  document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
  result = false;
 }

 if(n!=4)  
 {
  msg+="You must enter a 4 digit number \n" ;
 document.ExamEntry.exam.focus();
 document.getElementById('exam').style.color="red";
  result=false;
 }


 if(msg=="")
 { 
  return result;
 }
 else
 {
  alert(msg)
  return result;
 }
}

<body> 
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
 <tr>
  <td id="name">Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="subject">Subject</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td id="exam">Examination Number</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="exam" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
  <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
 </tr>+
</table> 
</form> 
</body>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="educationlevel" value="GCSE"> GCSE<br>
  <input type="radio" name="educationlevel" value="AS"> AS<br>
  <input type="radio" name="educationlevel" value="A2"> A2<br>
</form>
```

I want to create another function that displays an alert msg that asks that "is this the level you chose, please confirm" I've tried different options such as

```
function confirm () {
     var alerttxt = "Are you sure you want to choose",
         value = document.ExamEntry.educationlevel.value;

     alerttxt += value;

     alert(alerttxt);
Elseif alert("Pick a level of study")
    }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It works but it proceeds to the "success" page even if other function was not valid. I need help so when only both functions are valid it displays the "success" page.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send a form only if some fields are correctly filed. For this simply add at your form that contains the `sending option`(the submit button) :

```
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

Where your function return **false** if everything isn't correct. By sending **false**, the form won't be submited. If everything is correct just send **true**. In your exemple it should look like this :

```
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

and your submit button :

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

For your confirmation alert box simply use a prompt box where you can have 2 buttons like "OK" or "return".

To check whether or not one of the radiobutton is checked use something like :

```
for(var i in document.forms[1]){
            if(document.forms[1].elements[i].checked);
```

or give a name to your second form that checks the radio button

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.

1. You are using two separate forms for the input fields and for the radio fields, but you are calling the radio fields with the name of the first form.
2. You are overwriting the default "confirm" function.  You need to use `confirm` rather than `alert` in your last function, so you need to change your `confirm` function to a different name
3. You should also be testing if `educationlevel` has been chosen before the prompt rather than afterward